# How to replace blank value to 0 in a matrix

Tags: linux, csv, matrix

I have a 37 * 4980 matrix in CSV file format. I want to replace the blank value to 0. How can I accomplish this using bash script or linux command?

I tried my best to post a section of the file but it's difficult to format here so I post a picture here:
[image]

Those "ATTTCT.." is the column and CD27 is the row in the matrix, since my file is very large so only show CD27 here but actually I have 37 rows, the number is the value in the matrix. So I'm not sure is "," delimitated.

Comment: Please post samples of input along with sample of expected output in your post and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 my file is too large and very difficult to format here

Comment: Sure, we need not to post exact Input_file, just sample which is very near to your actual Input_file will work too, cheers :)  Also please post your efforts which you have put in your post too.

Comment: Can you post an image of the expected output? If I figure this out, I might post an image of the solution.

Comment: How are two rows distinguished from one another

Answer (score 1):

I use sed alot:

```
sed 's/word1/word2/g' input.file
## *bsd/macos sed syntax#
sed 's/word1/word2/g' input.file > output.file
sed -i 's/word1/word2/g' input.file
sed -i -e 's/word1/word2/g' -e 's/xx/yy/g' input.file
## use + separator instead of / ##
sed -i 's+regex+new-text+g' file.txt
```

The above replace all occurrences of characters in `word1` in the pattern space with the corresponding characters from `word2`.

replace `word1` with your empty field (ie.  `''`, or `""`, or `,,`)
and replace `word2` with your intended value (ie. `0` or `,0,` if you use the 2-comma example)

Comment: dose this works for a matrix? I tried but not work. actually I'm not sure if it's tab delaminate in csv for a matrix

Comment: so, you are looking at a csv file.  the size is irrelevent.  what you are doing is character-based replace in a linux setting.  which is why I recommended using `sed`.  what you need to know is how the `nulls` are being identified so you can set the `word1` and `word2` parameters.